# Passing a var as an argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a site I'm making I need to have a progress bar, I found one that suited my needs. By default it will incrementally change the color when a certain percentage is reached (0-30 red, 30-70 orange, etc). My only problem is changing them, I can set them easily with a static number such as 50, but when I try to do it dynamically (ie: 2000*.3 = 600) it fails. I don't know much js/jquery so this is especially difficult for me, if you could help that would be great. I'm pretty sure it's something really simple I'm missing.

The code that Fails:

```
var barmax = 2000;
var orangeBound = Math.round(barmax * .3);
var greenBound  = Math.round(barmax * .7);
//alert(orangeBound+":"+greenBound);
$("#pb1").progressBar({ max: barmax, textFormat: 'fraction',
barImage: {
       0: 'images/progressbg_red.gif',
       orangeBound: 'images/progressbg_orange.gif',
       greenBound: 'images/progressbg_green.gif'}
    });
```

The code that works but I can't use because it has to be dynamic:

```
$("#pb1").progressBar({ max: barmax, textFormat: 'fraction',
    barImage: {
       0: 'images/progressbg_red.gif',
       600: 'images/progressbg_orange.gif',
       1400: 'images/progressbg_green.gif'}
    });
```

If you need to see the source, [here](http://t.wits.sg/misc/jQueryProgressBar/demo.php). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that using `orangeBound` as the key in the object literal means that the string `"orangeBound"` is used, rather than the value of the variable. Instead, try building the object like so:

```
var barImage = {0: 'images/progressbg_red.gif'};
barImage[orangeBound] = 'images/progressbg_orange.gif';
barImage[greenBound] = 'images/progressbg_green.gif'
var barmax = 2000;
var orangeBound = Math.round(barmax * .3);
var greenBound  = Math.round(barmax * .7);
$("#pb1").progressBar({
    max: barmax,
    textFormat: 'fraction',
    barImage: barImage
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In JS, {orangeBound: "foo"} will just result in a key called "orangeBound" containing the value "foo". You'll have to build the object separately:

```
var barImages = {0: 'images/progressbg_red.gif'};
barImages[orangeBound] = 'images/progressbg_orange.gif';
// ...
$(...).progressBar({..., barImage: barImages});
```

Comment: Thank you. That saved me a lot of time.